# biased coin probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

when a biased coin is tossed 5 times the probability of having 2 heads is same as that of having 3 (and not 0) What is the probability of having heads exactly 3 out of 5?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint:  suppose the probability of throwing $H$ is $p$.  What, then, is the probability of throwing exactly $2$ heads?  exaclty $3$?  Of course, your answers will depend on $p$...but then setting them to be equal should let you compute $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of having two heads is 
$$
\binom{5}{2} p^2(1-p)^3 = 10  p^2(1-p)^3 
$$
The probability of having three heads is 
$$
\binom{5}{2} p^3(1-p)^2 = 10  p^3(1-p)^2 
$$
Solving 
$$
10  p^2(1-p)^3 =10  p^3(1-p)^2 
$$
gives $p=0$ (which is excluded by your conditions), $p=\frac12$ (which is the anser wthe problem poser probably wants), and $p=1$ (which is the anser wthe problem poser probably overlooked).

Comment: *Note:* The condition that $\binom{5}{2}p^2(1-p)^3~=~\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2~\neq~0$ excludes *both* $p=0$ *and* $p=1$